How can I view the percentage of recipients who opened an email in Outlook on the web?
I was able to view the percentage of recipients who opened an email in Outlook on the web:

I don't know how that appeared. I only see this stats for that email, and I couldn't see it in the other emails I opened.
How can I view the percentage of recipients who opened an email in Outlook on the web?

To be able to view the percentage of recipients who opened an email in Outlook on the web, there are at least 2 conditions from my understanding:

At least 5 Outlook recipients.
The email was sent no more than 14 days ago.

